# How can I generate an array from each line of a textarea with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to create a textarea who's input is bound to a JS array where entries correspond to each line in the text area.

I've been attempting to use [`ngList`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList) with it's optional parameter to specify the *delimiter*. I *can* make it work with the default (`,`) by adding a comma after each line of the textarea, but I really do not want to require that.

**the textarea**

```
<textarea ng-model="list"
          rows="5"
          ng-list="\n" >
</textarea>
```

with the input:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

The generated output is `["test1\ntest2\ntest3"]`

What I am looking for is: `["test1","test2",test3"]`

[<kbd>**Plnkr Demo**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/JuRsLNugiGvj4qkowAPc?p=preview)

Comment: Do you mean["test1","test2","test3"]?

Comment: @ChrisC yes, thank you for catching that, updating now

Comment: @ZachL I'm interested to see how you handle the initial binding... (because as soon as you add something it condenses your array to one string `["test1, test2, test3","something new"]`  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/wKquG/21/

Comment: @Nix, I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean... could you provide a demo perhaps (or if its worth it, a new question)? Check out [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6iSRTX8j2HtXywM1nwlX?p=preview)

Comment: I gave you a sample, just initialize your list with something in it ( $scope.list = ["1","2"];.  Type a key in the text area and your list will now be ["1,2", "New item"]

Comment: oh yes, I see your issue now. A damn good question. Luckily I don't have to modify that $scope variable outside of the `textarea`, nor do I need to provide any default values. Please consider creating another question asking about this -- and paste a link here. I'd be very interested to see the solution, and would certainly toss an upvote your way ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was updated in Angular 1.3 and now works like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="list" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

- add `ng-trim="false"` directive to the `<textarea>` tag
- use the ASCII code for newline character: `&#10;`

Comment: In case I want to update the ng-model and want to reflect it in the textarea, it does not work with ng-trim and ng-list attributes. When i remove it works. But i need this feature.

Answer (score 5):

### **EDIT:** As of **Angular 1.3**, this answer is obsolete.

#### Please refer to [@OrangeSalty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28223151/363701)

---

*From [the (1.2) ngList docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/directive/ngList):*

> If specified in form /something/ then the value will be converted into a regular expression.

I just added the `/`'s and it magically worked!

```
<textarea ng-model="list"
          rows="5"
          ng-list="/\n/" >
</textarea>
```

[<kbd>**updated plnkr demo**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/6iSRTX8j2HtXywM1nwlX?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You could split the output angular gives you:

```
var result = ["test1\ntest2\ntest3"][0].split("\n")

// result = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

(Although the solution you've posted is much better!)

Comment: Thanks Chris! This certainly would work, but of course I'll go for the more idiomatic approach. Funny how I bang my head against this for an hour, then within almost seconds of posting on SO, I get it working.

Comment: look like you miss the `ngList`.