# Angularjs: Printing an Array model with new lines in a TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, textarea

I have a simple textarea control,

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <textarea ng-model="myArray"></textarea>
  </div>
```

and a model that is an array of strings:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myArray = [
      "something1", 
      "something2",
      "something3",
   ];    
}
```

Im trying to get it so that every entry is on its own line:

```
something1 
something2
something3
```

And for extra credit would like to resplit the text back into an array on hte model side.

I've tried a few things, including [ng-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940915/how-can-i-generate-an-array-from-each-line-of-a-textarea-with-angularjs), [custom directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586159/angularjs-format-array-values-in-textarea), custom filters, and ng-repeat, but haven't gotten any where.

fiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8162/

Comment: My _feeling_ is that a filter is proper here, but i couldn't get it to work with the two way binding in ng-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. There is no textarea in the fiddle.

You can doctor your array to have new line characters at the end of each string. Not sure if that helps?

```
$scope.myArr = ['111\n', '222\n', '333\n']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8161/

Your fiddle has quite a lot of info in, maybe make it simpler? Showing input and output.

Edit:

Is it for input and output? If just for output, you could just do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8164/

Comment: oops, included the wrong fiddle. Fixed now. The crux of the question is around teh best way to add those '\n'. I thought angular had more magic around converting the models to a nice display format and back [citation needed].

Comment: yeah its ultimately for a REST get and post. I was hoping for a cleaner encapsulation of this rather than just serializing/deserializing the array every time in the controller, but then, i guess thats what controllers are there for...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to have two vars. Essentially your textarea is a text string. So if you need an array then set up a watcher on the string model.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8165/

```
$scope.myStr = 'aaaa\nbbbb\nccccc';
$scope.$watch('myStr', function(myStr){
    $scope.myArray = myStr.split('\n');
    console.log('$scope.myArray', $scope.myArray);
});
```